# test whether 2 values are significantly different based on sample distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a sample distribution based on 500 observations.

[image]

Based on distribution, is it possible to show that 2 numbers `4.33` and `8.55` are significantly different from each other? Which statistical test should be utilized?

Thanks indeed.

Comment: Of course 4.33 and 8.55 differ--mathematics tells you that.  Could you please explain what these numbers *mean* or *measure*, how they might be related to your data, and what you mean by "significant"?

Comment: Dear whuber, I have a summary score for certain metric, which was used to quantify 500 different observations. The distribution of 500 scores is shown in the figure and it is clear, that mostly score is in the range of [-5.5; 5.5]. Now, I want to show that score of 4.33 and 8.55 are significantly different. (If the score was in the range of -10000 to 10000, then a difference between 4.33 and 8.55 is very small and probably NOT significant) Is it possible, given the above distribution (knowing that score is mostly between -5.5 and 5.5) show how significant the difference between 4.33 and 8.55?

Comment: The concept of "significance" implied by your comment does not sound like a statistical one: it appears to be a question of what you find to be meaningfully large.

Comment: Dear whuber, what would be your suggestion to show that 2 numbers are significantly different from a statistical perspective? Is it possible to get p-value by utilizing some statistical test to show this difference? Do I need some other data to do this? Thank you indeed!

Comment: No, no p-value is possible because the concept does not apply.  You haven't stated or even suggested a null hypothesis that could be tested.